# Passing XlBorderWeight to Procedure

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to correct not my code. I noticed repeatable code:

```
With selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlMedium
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With

With selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
```

First, I wrote a procedure:

```
Sub BorderAutomatic(border As border)
    border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    border.Weight = xlThin
    border.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End Sub

BorderAutomatic (selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight))
```

to shorten all cases where weight is thin, now I would like to shorten cases where weight is medium. To do this I add next argument:

```
Sub BorderAutomatic(border As border, borderWeight As XlBorderWeight)
    border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    'border.Weight = xlThin
    border.Weight = borderWeight
    border.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End Sub

BorderAutomatic (selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight), xlThin)
```

I get an Error: 'Expected: ='

How should I write this?

Comment: `BorderAutomatic (selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight), xlThin)` Should be `BorderAutomatic selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight), xlThin`

Comment: Parentheses strike again.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't have parentheses in the first code snippet either: `BorderAutomatic selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)`.